# Rendering Date picker of jquery in wicket page

Tags: jquery, datepicker, wicket

I had a small issue in Wicket with datepicker.

I have a jquery datepicker which i included it in a wicket page, on page load. it is displaying that date picker, when ever i clicked on submit button then date picker is disabling (not even displaying calendar.gif).

Comment: Can you show the relevant code to how you are using this component? (html and java)

Answer (score 0):

if the submit button is a ajax component you must append the javascript of your calendar for example

```
 AjaxButton button=new AjaxButton("button", form) {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = -8842723332530791101L;

        @Override
        protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> 
            target.appendJavaScript(yorJavaScript);
        }

};
```